# get home screen wallpaper android

Tags: android, background, wallpaper, homescreen

i want to set a background wallpaper in my application same with home screen wallpaper in my android. So, how to get home screen wallpaper in activity_main.xml or mainActivity.java?
Can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call [WallpaperManager#getDrawable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getDrawable()) method, which should return the current system wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

Use wallpaper theme in activity_main.xml